# Browser component in Winforms C#

Tags: .net, winforms

Hopefully someone can help.

At work, I have been given the task of searching for an alternative to the WebBrowser control in .net for an application.

The scenario is the WebBrowser call’s internally a url to another company and the returned site is then showed in the view of the WebBrowser, so it seems it is integrated in the application.

But on newer versions of IE the WebBrowser can’t show the returned site if you’re not running the application as admin (That is not optimal and is the main issue) on pc’s that are managed by a supervisor.

To simply asking the supervisor to allow the site returned is not allowed. 
As I understand the WebBrowser, is it is a wrapper for the latest IE installed on your machine.

And the later versions of the IE browsers are more and more restricted for what to show.

Question is if anyone can help width an alternative that is not as restrict as IE.

The Browser component should support webhook’s.

I am open to suggestions.

Comment: http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

If its matter of rendering issues with IE then you may use alternative rendering engines like [Gecko](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/embedding-web-browsers-in-winform-applications/) explained in this post

Same question already answered:

[Replacing .NET WebBrowser control with a better browser, like Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)

[Replacing Latest .NET WebBrowser Control with a browser, like Firefox or Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221905/replacing-latest-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-browser-like-firefox-or-chrome)

Comment: The matter is not in rendering. It is a properly security issue.   
Can’t ask a supervisor on a local network to allow the site because of company politics. (In older IE versions the return site is shown and in never version the site is not showed).
If there is another browser that default don’t have these restrictions, it would solve the issue.
Can’t change the restrictions on the pc via the application is installed on, Couse it is under a supervisor pc.